# How to get request details and table name in custom repository - Loopback 4?

Tags: typescript, express, repository, loopback, loopback4

I am using **LB4** and I am extending all repositories from a Custom `BaseRepository` which `extends` the `DefaultCrudRepository`, I haven't done anything special in this repo, just called the `super.methods()`, one method is:

```
create(entity: DataObject<T>, options?: Options): Promise<T> {
  return super.create(entity, options);
}
```

Now, I need to create a log entry whenever the record is saved, updated or deleted. Log entry will have something like this:

```
{
  tableName: string,
  ip: string,
  browser: string
}
```

Now, I am confused how to get table name and the request details in the repository.

I have `@inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) public request: Request` in my controller but I don't know how to use it, any suggestions?

Comment: Today, have you find a solution ? I have the same problem. I think it is not possible to intercept the actual context in the repository layer (see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1919). For your case, you can create an entity with your structure, and an @interceptor which intercept the HTTP request and store its data inside your entity before saving it.

Comment: Nevermind, I left that project and using NestJS now.

Answer (score 0):

First import `Request` from `@loopback/rest`

Second, `@inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) public request: Request` at controller constructor

- `request.headers["user-agent"]` has browser data.
- `request.ip` has IP. But note that you have to put this directive `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` into your `nginx` configuration in case you are using your own reverse proxy. For `apache`, do accordingly.
- Table name is obvious as you know where you create record.

Comment: Thanks for response but I think you didn't my question! I have asked about custom repository not controller.

Comment: Try `this.modelClass.modelName` or `this.modelClass.name` for table name. This is the model class name but I think table name is the same